# django, haystack, and pyelasticsearch best versions

Tags: django, django-haystack, pyelasticsearch

Basically, I am getting a unreasonable amount of errors using these libraries:

```
django==1.4.3
pyelasticsearch==0.6
simplejson==3.3.0
django-haystack==2.1.0
```

The errors I get are:

- From python2.7/site-packages/haystack/query.py:
  `index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'`
  I just remove this and it works locallay
- /srv/www/projects/k-state-union/lib/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py:
  `raise MissingDependency("The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'pyelasticsearch'. Please refer to the documentation.")`
  This error occurs when pyelasticsearch fails to be imported. If I let it fail naturally:
- /srv/www/.virtualenvs/k-state-union/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py:
  `from simplejson import JSONDecodeError`
  Which works in the python interpreter.

The errors seem to indicate that I am not using the intended versions of `pyelasticsearch` and `haystack`. What do I need to do to get this up and running?

Comment: are you using `virtualenv`?

Comment: @HieuNguyen Yes, I do use virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different python libraries for Elasticsearch out there. I switched from pyelasticsearch to elasticsearch and it worked.